# Protocol interface in framework is not recognized in client code

Tags: swift, inheritance, frameworks, protocols

I wrote a set of interfaces for some models, within the framework, and they have a direct dependency relationship. When used in the client code, compliance with one of the protocols is not recognized. Requiring that I have to use the type defined in the interface, and not one that conforms to the protocol.

Code in Framework:

```
import Foundation

public protocol HomeEntityProtocol {
    var items: [ItemEntity]? { get set }
    var title: String? { get set }
    var type: Int? { get set }
}

public protocol ItemEntity {
    var title: String? { get set }
    var image: String? { get set }
    var subtitle: String? { get set }
}
```

Code in side client:

```
// MARK: - Home
struct HomeEntity: Codable, HomeEntityProtocol {
    var items: [Item]?
    var title: String?
    var type: Int?
}

struct Item: Codable, ItemEntity {
    var title: String?
    var image: String?
    var subtitle: String?
}
```

The message error is: `Type 'HomeEntity' does not conform to protocol 'HomeEntityProtocol'`.

Requiring the following implementation:

```
struct HomeEntity: Codable, HomeEntityProtocol {
var items: [ItemEntity]?
// ...
```

How to recognize / accept protocol inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

### What is the problem?

You try to implement a nice design that is based on [**covariance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)): a class that adopts a protocol with an array, but prefers to restrict the use of another protocol to one of its subtype:

[image]

The advantage of this design -- if it would work -- would be that `HomeEntity` could assume the `items` to be more specialized than `ItemEntity`, and as a consequence use additional properties and methods.

### Why doesn't this work?

Unfortunately, [Swift protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) require conforming classes to match  **exactly** their specifications.  Each conforming class is considered independently. This does not allow any covariance. In other words, `items` in `HomeEntity` must stay an `ItemEntity` as required in the `HomeEntityProtocol`:

[image]

The drawback is that `HomeEntity` cannot assume each of the `items` to be an `Item` (since any other subtype of `ItemEntity` could be used).  It can therefore not use additional properties or methods out of the box, without proper [downcasting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID341).

*Side remark: While some would argue that such limitation is a flaw that should be urgently fixed by the language designers,  I'd prefer to consider it as a feature that encourages [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if conforming classes would be allowed to restrict related protocols to some subtype, then you'd strengthen the preconditions every time you'd add new items, and LSP would be infringed.*

### What solution?

There is no built-in solution to your problem in Swift.  Generics combined with protocols don't address the issue either.

The best way to address your issue is probably to revise your design and opt for a "[tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)" approach, in which `HomeEntity` would have to know nothing but the `ItemEntity` protocol, and let the `ItemEntity`  get the things done.

If this is not possible, you could alternatively opt for a workaround:   ensure that only `Items` can be inserted into the `items`, and then use some kind of shortcuts for easy downcasting, e.g. a computed property,  or a `getItem(n: Int) -> Item` for convenient access.